# The concepts of conditional mean and variance in time series: semantic issues

Tags: time-series, conditional-expectation, conditional-variance

In time series, the concepts of a "conditional mean" $E_{t}(X_{t+1})$ and "conditional variance" $V_{t}(X_{t+1})$ is semantically unclear to me. Would anyone be able to clearly explain (references welcome):

- How can we compute these with data? I understand in the contexts other than time series, we have different population strata, so it's easy to compute a conditional mean (eg the average income given a level of education...). But if I have a stock return $X$ eg, $E_{t}(X_{t+1})$ is unknown. So can we speak about "conditional mean" here in the time series context, and how can we compute a conditional mean in this case?
- For the conditional variance, I have the same semantic issue as above, + another one. To me we cannot know ex ante and thus not compute a condional variance in time series. So the relevant concept should be "conditional expected variance" (how I expect the data to be dispersed around my expectation) and not "conditional variance". If I'm right, why don't we say $E_{t}(V_{t}(X_{t+1}))$ instead of $V_{t}(X_{t+1})$ (which I know ends up being the same, but my issue is why we don't call it the way it should be called)?

Comment: Can you clarify your post? When we talk about conditional mean and variance, we always condition on something. In a time series context, we may condition on previous values of the variable of interest.  The notation in your post does not make it clear what you are conditioning on.

Comment: Thxs. I am in a time series context (asset pricing context for my case but I think the question applies to the broader context of time series). In this context, conditional on t means "conditional on all information at time t". So $E_{t}(X_{t+1})$ would be the mean of $X_{t+1}$ conditional on all information we have at time t.

Comment: I think it will be easier if you work your way through a simple case - compute the conditional mean and variance of an MA(1) or AR(1) process, as described here for example: https://www.kevinsheppard.com/images/c/cf/Chapter4.pdf. Then you can understand what is going on.